# Como conectar aplicativos desktop e web?

Tags: web-service

A ideia do meu TCC é fazer um programa onde os professores poderão lançar as notas via internet e onde os alunos poderão visualizá-las. Também haverá uma parte desktop onde a secretária da escola cadastrará os alunos e professores e fará alguns relatórios. Como eu faço para linkar essa parte Web com a Desktop?

Comment: O nome do que você está procurando é Banco de Dados

Answer (score 6):

Neste caso você ira ter vários programas e não apenas um.

- Você terá uma aplicação web que será a responsável por toda a lógica e armazenamento.
- Clientes desktop (pode-se ter também clientes mobile)
- API para comunicação da sua Aplicação Web com os seus clientes, esta API será um WebService.

Na aplicação web você terá: Gestão de usuários, Gestão de disciplinas, Gestão de matriculas, Gestão de lançamentos de nota, Etc. Ela terá todas as ações e responsabilidades possíveis da sua aplicação

A API é uma interface na qual através da internet as aplicações Desktop, Mobile (android, iOS, Windows Phone) podem interagir com seu site, coisas como autenticação, obter lista de alunos, enviar notas, etc.

As aplicações Desktop e Mobile neste caso serão clientes da API, isso quer dizer, que elas irão depender da aplicação web, para evitar duplicidade de dados e os perigos que isso traz como dados desatualizados por exemplo as aplicações Desktop e Mobile irão fazer chamadas via a API para realizar o lançamento de notas, obter notas de alunos e assim por diante.

A estrutura normal de uma aplicação web seria:

- WebServer - Responsável pela lógica do programa.
- DataBase Server - Responsável pelo armazenamento das informações.
- API server - Responsável por oferecer a interface para acesso, normalmente separado do web server porque se um der problema o outro não será afetado, também ajuda a dividir a carga.

As aplicações desktop e mobile terão:

- Lógica básica de consumo, por exemplo um formulário que pede usuário e senha, envia para o servidor e ao receber a mensagem de sucesso permite o uso da aplicação.
- Interface WebService compatível com a usada pela API.

As vezes eu posso ser um pouco confuso, mas o que você vai ter é mais o menos duas categorias de programas, a Aplicação Web que centraliza tudo e as outras que consomem os dados.

Answer (score 0):

Escolha a linguagem e plataforma que voce mais domina, 
crie a estrutura principal nela!

Exemplo da estrutura principal:

Banco de Dados : MySQL

Plataforma     : Windows -> .net -> C#

Clientes Externos:

Web    -> Asp.net/MVC
Mobile -> ANDROID

dessa forma você tem a estrutura principal em um ambiente que você domina, faça os clientes externos apenas conectarem ao seu banco de dados no servidor Local Mesmo!!

espero que possa ter ajudado!!

FLW!!

Comment: seria legal vc dar mais detalhes de como fazer os clientes se conectarem a(s) base(s) de dados, ficou vago, do jeito que está não sei se sua resposta será de grande ajuda

Comment: O problema com o servidor local seria o caso onde os professores iriam realizar o lançamento via internet, neste caso o servidor de aplicação tem que estar visível na internet, permitindo que seja possível lançar as notas e salva-las, o ideal seria ter um servidor web, este não precisa estar hospedado longe, mas precisa ser acessível pela web, para reduzir a carga de logica e validação seria interessante montar apenas clientes nos Desktop ao invés de aplicações completas, deixando assim o código mais fácil de manter. Depois se quiser mudar a logica você muda apenas na web. (depend. da logic.)