# Criar uma aplicação Java para WEB que rode também via desktop

Tags: java, html, html5, aplicação-web, javafx

Boa noite a todos.

Estou pensando em desenvolver uma aplicação com as seguintes caracteristicas:

**Backend:** Java

**Frontend(Opção 1):** JavaFX

**Frontend(Opção 2):** HTML5 + CSS3

Quero começar do jeito certo, internacionalizando a aplicação com resource bundle, etc, etc, etc. Porém, também quero que a minha aplicação rode via desktop, mas que seja acessível também via web.

Resumindo minha dúvida: Quais as ferramentas para se desenvolver uma aplicação Java que rode via Desktop e também via web? Meu backend muda ao desenvolver para um e para outro? ou apenas as interfaces? agradeço desde já.

Obs.: Ouvi falar em Java Web start, mas pelo que li ele projeta uma aplicação java desktop para a web, mas não faz o contrário.

**[Resultado]**

Conversei hoje com um amigo e grande desenvolvedor, e montei a seguinte estrutura de estudo para inserção no mercado de trabalho:

**1) JAVA**

**2) JSF**

**3) MVC**

**4) JAVASCRIPT + HTML5 + CSS3 + AJAX**

Consegui entender também que o Backend ideal trabalha para diversas front-end, e que não existe uma universal, e mesmo que seja possível, não é viavel comercialmente pois cada tela, seja ela mobile, desktop ou web, tem suas particularidades. 
Já vi páginas espetaculares se reduzirem a projetos caseiros simplesmente por desenvolverem uma interface web sem considerar a estrutura de acesso via mobile. Facebook mesmo tem dificuldade em portabilizar recursos do browser desktop para browsers mobile, apesar dos esforços. 
Acho que o que pude aprender nesta discussão foi que o modelo ideal de projeto deve contemplar um backend robusto com linguagem de programação e banco de dados(na maioria dos casos) e um front-end para cada tipo de cliente (web, desktop, mobile, até mesmo acesso via console lynx por exemplo). 
Meu intuito como aspirante a "aspirante de programador", é máximizar meu conhecimento em Java SE e java EE, e com isso virar um expert em desenvolvimento para multiplataformas.

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Pesquise um pouco sobre web service, existe uma pergunta com uma resposta que fala sobre a estrutura que você vai precisar (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8071/como-conectar-aplicativos-desktop-e-web)

Comment: Java é uma plataforma só, é necessário o Runtime para executar tanto em Desktop para Web, não há "Java para Web" ou "Java para Desktop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML5 + CSS3.

O motivo é que se você pretende programar para a web, o ideal é que o usuário esteja executando o seu programa por meio do navegador, e assim, basta ele saber a URL do seu programa e já será capaz de acessá-lo.

No caso do desktop, a solução é a mesma, a única diferença é que o endereço a ser acessado será no `localhost` ou coisa parecida.

HTML5 + CSS3 é amplamente difundido e qualquer um tem um navegador capaz de lidar com isso sem que você precise pedir para o usuário instalar nada.

O JavaFX por outro lado é a rigor para aplicações desktop, tal como o Swing e o AWT.

A ideia até era permitir que o JavaFX fosse usado para o desenvolvimento de RIA (*Rich Internet Applications*), mas isso não vingou porque dependia da possibilidade de rodar o JavaFX dentro de applets. Ocorre que todos os navegadores modernos descontinuaram o uso de applets, o que matou e enterrou de vez esta possibilidade. Assim sendo, restou ao JavaFX viver apenas no desktop.

Comment: Estive lendo agora neste meio tempo um artigo interessantíssimo sobre o Electron: https://www.linuxdescomplicado.com.br/2016/09/saiba-como-criar-aplicacoes-desktop-multiplataforma-usando-javascript-html-e-css.html.

esta ferramenta de desenvolvimento permite a criação de aplicações multiplataformas, e permite também que aplicações web sejam portadas para desktop.

Comment: @AlexandreGuerreiro Há várias ferramentas desse tipo espalhadas por aí de todos os gostos e qualidades e certamente que mais algumas estão sendo inventadas neste exato momento, mas no final todas elas geram HTML + JS + CSS para rodar no navegador. O que ocorre é que essas ferramentas podem gerar tudo ou parte disso para você.